# Python Networkx: Add duplicate or equal nodes to a tree / graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, quantitative-finance

I am working with a directed graph in Networkx which I need to "split" in two. The graph represents a recombinant trinomial tree and after building it I need to do some calculations with the values on the nodes.

My problem is that I am working on an application with requires me to check a node and "split" the tree. I need to have duplicate node values because their location on the graph is what matters to me, not the value on the node itself. Note: Re-naming the nodes (i.e. changing node 10 to 10a) is not a feasible since I have to do calculations with those numbers later.

As an example:

```
     80 
      |
     100
   /  |  \
 50  100  150
```

and I need to end up with:

```
          80 
       /      \    
      100      100
    /  |        |
  50  100      150
```

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT renaming the nodes???  Thank you!

Comment: Traveling all son nodes to create `root --> first_son` `root --> second_son`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you say. I can't get Python to do duplicate nodes.

Comment: @MiguelHerschberg One option is to have the actual value eg: `100` as an attribute of the node but have distinct nodes to form the edges. (So, in your example, the two 100's here would be 100a and 100b, but both have an attribute of 100 used for calculations)

Comment: @JonClements I REALLY would like not to do that because i added the nodes as g.add_node(100), and what would fix the code would to doing g.add_node(100a, value=100) right? However is part of a long program and if I change this I need to restructure the code. Is there anyway of doing this without renaming the nodes?

Comment: @MiguelHerschberg Different nodes need to be different objects. Simple as that I'm afraid... and yep, that would be the way to do it...

Answer (score 3):

Could you just add values to nodes? Some amount of restructuring is probably unavoidable. `value` could be anything so that allows you to keep the nodes you already have and differentiate between them...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1,value=80)
G.add_node(2,value=100)
G.add_node(3,value=50)
G.add_node(4,value=100)
G.add_node(5,value=150)
G.add_node(6,value=100)
G.add_node(7)
G.add_node(8)
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(1,6),(6,5)])

# change the value of nodes
for i in G:
    if 'value' in G.node[i]:
        # do something?
        continue
    else:
        G.node[i]['value']=200


labels={}
for i in G:
    labels[i]=G.node[i]['value']
pos=nx.circular_layout(G)

nx.draw_circular(G,node_size=1000,node_color='r',node_shape='s',with_labels=False)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=12)
plt.show()
```